# How to call a function, when collada textures were loaded? (Three.js)

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js, collada

```
loader.load( 'path/to/collada.dae', function ( collada ) {
  // This function is called, when collada were loaded.

});
```

But how to call a function, when the textures were loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The ColladaLoader class uses THREE.ImageUtils to load textures on [line 3087](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/ColladaLoader.js#L3087). The ImageUtils class [has the ability](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/ImageUtils.js#L10) to give a callback when the image is loaded, but ColladaLoader doesn't use it.

You can create a workaround by traversing the collada scene looking for images. Here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4mSMM/). The relevant code is:

```
THREE.SceneUtils.traverseHierarchy( dae.scene, function (object) {
    if (object.material && object.material.map) {
        object.material.map.image.onload = function() {
            console.log('image loaded');
            object.material.map.needsUpdate = true;
        };
    }
});
```

This prints "image loaded" to the console when each texture is loaded.